# typescript import function from 3rd party declare module

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I have run `npm install --save-dev @types/d3-box`

How do I import it into my angular 7 project?

I have create a file **custom-d3.ts**  that looks like:

```
export * from 'd3-axis';
export * from 'd3-brush';
export * from 'd3-chord';
export * from 'd3-collection';
export * from 'd3-color';
export * from 'd3-contour';
export * from 'd3-dispatch';
export * from 'd3-drag';
export * from 'd3-dsv';
export * from 'd3-ease';
export * from 'd3-fetch';
export * from 'd3-force';
export * from 'd3-format';
export * from 'd3-geo';
export * from 'd3-hierarchy';
export * from 'd3-interpolate';
export * from 'd3-path';
export * from 'd3-polygon';
export * from 'd3-quadtree';
export * from 'd3-random';
export * from 'd3-scale';
export * from 'd3-scale-chromatic';
export * from 'd3-selection';
export * from 'd3-shape';
export * from 'd3-time';
export * from 'd3-time-format';
export * from 'd3-timer';
export * from 'd3-transition';
export * from 'd3-voronoi';
export * from 'd3-zoom';
export * from 'd3-box';
```

In my component I import the custom-d3 as d3 witch includes the d3-box.
`import * as d3 from '../custom-d3';`

In my code I want to call d3.box() like below:

```
this.boxPlot = d3.box()
   .whiskers(this.iqr(1.5))
   .height(this.graphHeight)
   .showLabels(this.labels);
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
  ERROR in src/app/components/d3/group-graph/box-graph.ts(115,27): error TS2339: Property 'box' does not exist on type 'typeof import("custom-d3")'.
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a `custom-d3.ts` when you are already installing the types?

Comment: I can import 
`
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3Box from 'd3-box';
`
but could not get it to work, 
`
this.boxPlot = d3Box.box()
   .whiskers(this.iqr(1.5))
   .height(this.graphHeight)
   .showLabels(this.labels);
`

Answer (score 0):

I believe creating a [shared module](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) is the right use for your case.

First you need to create a new module `shared.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
//Import everything first
import * as d3Axis from 'd3-axis';
import * as d3Brush from 'd3-brush';
import * as d3Chord' from 'd3-chord';
// .. and so on

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    //declare component here if you want to share it with all other components.
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    d3Axis,
    d3Brush,
    d3Chord
  ],
  exports: [
    d3Axis,
    d3Brush,
    d3Chord
  ]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

Then, in any other Module where you want to use this module, you just need to only import it there.

Comment: I get this error if I try to do it in the way you suggested: 
`
Type 'typeof import("/node_modules/@types/d3-axis/index")' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.
  Property 'ngModule' is missing in type 'typeof import("/node_modules/@types/d3-axis/index")' but required in type 'ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.ts(2322)
core.d.ts(3755, 5): 'ngModule' is declared here.
`

Comment: Did you visited the link that i added above? I just showed you the concept of shared modules but you have to do it the way that is suitable to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Giacomo Debidda 
https://www.giacomodebidda.com/how-to-import-d3-plugins-with-webpack/

```
import * as d3Base from 'd3';
import * as box from 'd3-box';

// attach all d3 plugins to the d3 library
const d3 = Object.assign(d3Base, { box });
  .whiskers(this.iqr(1.5))
  .height(this.graphHeight);
```

And then when I use it:

```
this.boxPlot = (d3 as any).box()
```